# Why do I get segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c

**Why this question is not duplicate?**
The problem can't be at `scanf`, as it is given by the hackerrank and I can't modify the code! Also, test cases are automated, given by hackerrank. We can trust them with input reading. There is some bug in my logic of finding two elements in array, couldn't find it though :|

**Note:** I can't modify `main` method, as mentioned earlier. Re-iterating it. Why can't I modify? It is because the method is given by the portal. I can't change it. It reads the input and calls my method through some automated scripts, I've no control over it. So, please don't tell me to modify `main` method.

I was trying some practice problems in hackerrank in `C` language and some of the test cases started throwing `Segmentation fault` for following problem. I've tried understanding it for more than 2 hours now and couldn't think of any test case which will throw `segmentation fault`. I'm stuck :|

**Problem statement:**

> Given an array and a number. Find if there are 2 elements in array, whose sum is equal to given number. If number are present return 1, otherwise 0.

pretty easy, huh? I thought the same and coded it as follows,

```
int compFunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}


int isSumPossible(int a[], int L, int N ){
/*L: Length of the array */
    if(a==NULL) return 0;
    if(L<=1) return 0;
    int left=0, right=L-1;

    qsort(a,L,sizeof(int),compFunc);

    while(left<right)
        {
        if(a[left]+a[right]==N) return 1;
        else if(a[left]+a[right]<N) left++;
        else right--;    
    }
    return 0;
}
int main() //given by hackerrank, I can't modify main method
{
 int N; scanf("%d", &N); //fixed &N - it was correctly given in code, I missed it while typing it here.
 int a[100004], i=0;
 //read input into array a, based on N
 int x;scanf("%d", &x); //fixed &x - it was correctly given in code, I missed it while typing it here.
 printf("%d", isSumPossible(a,N,x));
}
```

Please assume all the header files required are included. Now, when I ran the code, most of the test cases passed and for some test cases they showed `Segmentation fault`. Unfortunately test cases aren't visible to me :|. I've gone through my code more than 10 times & I don't understand in which scenario I would get `Segmentaion fault`. Can anyone help me in understand which scenario am I missing in my code and why do I see segmentation fault?

Comment: Used a debugger to step through it? That's usually the best way to find these kinds of problems.

Comment: Also when asking other people to debug your code, please use spaces, like this: `if(a[left] + a[right] == N)`

Comment: Do you know what can *cause* a segmentation fault? If you knew, it would be really easy as you would know what to look for...

Comment: `scanf` needs address arguments to store the parsed values. i.e. `scanf("%d",&N);`, `scanf("%d",&x);`.

Comment: Using a 100004 size array on the stack is a terrible idea. You should really modify the main method, even if you say you can't.

Comment: That main function does not really make much sense. The ``a`` array is placed on stack and for 4 byte size of ``int`` the stack size would be about 400kB. On some whacko systems this might lead to problems.

Comment: May I suggest you provide prompts? When I run the program I'll just get a cursor. I might guess I am supposed to enter something, but what? Six months down the line this will help you too, as you are unlikely  to remember. The `N` and `x` in the program source won't be much help, as those names have no meaning. `printf("Enter the (whatever)\n");`

Comment: I can't use debugger, as it is online portal and I don't know what test cases it is giving. @KarolyHorvath I guess it is because of array index out of bound, not sure.

Comment: @Bregalad I can't modify main method, as it is automated portal were you  don't have control over reading input. You write the logic and test your logic.

Comment: @WeatherVane I missed typed it earlier. It was given correctly in main code. I've fixed it in code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the scanfs in the main part of the code.

If you look at documentation the function description even says:

> Reads data from stdin and stores them according to the parameter format into the **locations pointed** by the additional arguments.

This means you must give it a memory address to write data to. By adding `&` to both of your integer variables in your main the problem is solved.

```
int main() 
{
 int N; scanf("%d", &N);
 int a[100004], i=0;
 //read input into array a, based on N
 int x;scanf("%d", &x);
 printf("%d", isSumPossible(a,N,x));
}
```

Comment: I missed typed it in question. It was correctly given. Fixed my question.