# How can I establish a bijection between a tree and its traversal?

Tags: agda, idris

I was looking at [How does inorder+preorder construct unique binary tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556590/how-does-inorderpreorder-construct-unique-binary-tree/30566218#30566218) and thought it would be fun to write a formal proof of it in Idris. Unfortunately, I got stuck fairly early on, trying to prove that the ways to find an element in a tree correspond to the ways to find it in its inorder traversal (of course, I'll also need to do that for the preorder traversal). Any ideas would be welcome. I'm not particularly interested in a complete solution—more just help getting started in the right direction.

Given

```
data Tree a = Tip
            | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

I can convert it to a list in at least two ways:

```
inorder : Tree a -> List a
inorder Tip = []
inorder (Node l v r) = inorder l ++ [v] ++ inorder r
```

or

```
foldrTree : (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldrTree c n Tip = n
foldrTree c n (Node l v r) = foldr c (v `c` foldrTree c n r) l
inorder = foldrTree (::) []
```

The second approach seems to make pretty much *everything* difficult, so most of my efforts have focused on the first. I describe locations in the tree like this:

```
data InTree : a -> Tree a -> Type where
  AtRoot : x `InTree` Node l x r
  OnLeft : x `InTree` l -> x `InTree` Node l v r
  OnRight : x `InTree` r -> x `InTree` Node l v r
```

It's quite easy (using the first definition of `inorder`) to write

```
inTreeThenInorder : {x : a} -> (t : Tree a) -> x `InTree` t -> x `Elem` inorder t
```

and the result has a pretty simple structure that seems reasonably good for proofs.

It's also not terribly difficult to write a version of

```
inorderThenInTree : x `Elem` inorder t -> x `InTree` t
```

Unfortunately, I have not, thus far, come up with any way to write a version of `inorderThenInTree` that I've been able to prove is the inverse of `inTreeThenInorder`. The only one I've come up with uses

```
listSplit : x `Elem` xs ++ ys -> Either (x `Elem` xs) (x `Elem` ys)
```

and I run into trouble trying to get back through there.

A few general ideas I tried:

1. Using `Vect` instead of `List` to try to make it easier to work out what's on the left and what's on the right. I got bogged down in the "green slime" of it.
2. Playing around with tree rotations, going as far as to prove that rotation at the root of the tree lead to a well-founded relation. (I didn't play around with rotations below, because I never was able to figure out a way to *use* anything about these rotations).
3. Trying to decorate tree nodes with information about how to reach them. I didn't spend very long on this because I couldn't think of a way to express anything interesting through that approach.
4. Trying to construct the proof that we're going back where we started while constructing the function that does so. This got pretty messy, and I got stuck somewhere or other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were on the right track with your `listSplit` lemma. You can use that function to learn whether the target element is on the left or right side of a Tree. In the Agda standard library `listSplit` is called `++⁻`

This is the relevant line from my implementation

```
with ++⁻ (inorder l) x∈t
```

Here's the complete implementation. I've included it as an external link to avoid unwanted spoilers and also to take advantage of Agda's wonderful HTML hyperlinked, syntax highlighted output. You can click through to see the types and definitions of any of the supporting lemmas.

https://glguy.net/agda-tree-inorder-elem/Tree.html

Comment: I finally accomplished my original goal (proving that if a tree has no duplicate elements and has the same preorder and inorder traversals as another tree then the trees are equal). Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30566218/1477667). Suggestions for improvements would be very welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote `inorderToFro` and `inorderFroTo` and the associated lemmas in Idris. [Here's the link.](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/db8cc32b9b0f720596eb)

There are a couple of points I can make about your solution (without going much into details):

First, `splitMiddle` isn't really necessary. If you use a more general `Right p = listSplit xs ys loc -> elemAppend xs ys p = loc` type for `splitRight`, then that can cover the same ground.

Second, you could use more `with` patterns instead of explicit `_lem` functions; I think it would be clearer and more succinct as well.

Third, you do considerable work proving `splitLeft` and co. Often it makes sense to move the properties of a function *inside* the function. So, instead of writing `listSplit` and the proofs about its result separately, we can modify `listSplit` to return the needed proofs. This is often simpler to implement. In my solution I used the following types:

```
data SplitRes : (x : a) -> (xs, ys : List a) -> (e : Elem x (xs ++ ys)) -> Type where
  SLeft  : (e' : Elem x xs) -> e' ++^ ys = e -> SplitRes x xs ys e
  SRight : (e' : Elem x ys) -> xs ^++ e' = e -> SplitRes x xs ys e

listSplit : (xs, ys : List a) -> (e : Elem x (xs ++ ys)) -> SplitRes x xs ys e
```

I could have also used `Either (e' : Elem x xs ** (e' ++^ ys = e)) (e' : Elem x ys ** (xs ^++ e' = e))` instead of `SplitRes`. However, I ran into problems with `Either`. It seems to me that higher-order unification in Idris is just too wobbly; I couldn't comprehend why my `unsplitLeft` function wouldn't typecheck with `Either`. `SplitRes` doesn't contain functions in its type, so I guess that's why it works more smoothly.

In general, at this time I recommend Agda over Idris for writing proofs like this. It checks much faster and it's much more robust and convenient. I'm quite amazed you managed to write so much Idris here and for the other question about tree traversals.

Comment: Since I have too much time, I also wrote a [proof for the original question](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/d811108ab41fa85807e3) in Agda, FYI.

Comment: I think Idris has given me enough of a taste for dependent types to make me really want to learn Agda :P. The way I wrote so much was through sheer persistence.

Comment: Some of the explicit `lem` functions were necessitated by the need to dig into them in other proofs. Some of the others seemed forced on my by wacky type checker behavior in `with` clauses. Other times, I may not have known what I was doing.

Comment: I see that you came up with a different notion of "nodupness". Can you comment on what you think the advantages and disadvantages are?

Comment: The `NoDup`-s are basically because of my gut feeling that it would be better to go for a more fine-grained recursive definition. It seemed to me that I would have to prove things like "the root element is not in either subtrees" in any case. But I have no idea whether this is actually better than your definition, since I haven't tried both.

Comment: In case you thought I might not be completely insane, take a look at `BankerQueue.idr` and its lemmas in `BankerQueue/LazyLists` at https://github.com/treeowl/idris-containers/tree/bankers-queue/Data  There are all sorts of horrors; if you have an idea for making them less horrifying, GitHub issues would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work out how to prove that it's possible to go from a tree location to a list location and back from reading the types of the lemmas referenced in [glguy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625812/1477667). Eventually, I managed to go the other way too, although the code (below) is fairly horrible. Fortunately, I was able to reuse the terrifying list lemmas to prove the corresponding theorem about preorder traversals as well.

```
module PreIn
import Data.List
%default total

data Tree : Type -> Type where
  Tip : Tree a
  Node : (l : Tree a) -> (v : a) -> (r : Tree a) -> Tree a
%name Tree t, u

data InTree : a -> Tree a -> Type where
  AtRoot : x `InTree` (Node l x r)
  OnLeft : x `InTree` l -> x `InTree` (Node l v r)
  OnRight : x `InTree` r -> x `InTree` (Node l v r)

onLeftInjective : OnLeft p = OnLeft q -> p = q
onLeftInjective Refl = Refl

onRightInjective : OnRight p = OnRight q -> p = q
onRightInjective Refl = Refl

noDups : Tree a -> Type
noDups t = (x : a) -> (here, there : x `InTree` t) -> here = there

noDupsList : List a -> Type
noDupsList xs = (x : a) -> (here, there : x `Elem` xs) -> here = there

inorder : Tree a -> List a
inorder Tip = []
inorder (Node l v r) = inorder l ++ [v] ++ inorder r

rotateInorder : (ll : Tree a) ->
                (vl : a) ->
                (rl : Tree a) ->
                (v : a) ->
                (r : Tree a) ->
                inorder (Node (Node ll vl rl) v r) = inorder (Node ll vl (Node rl v r))
rotateInorder ll vl rl v r =
   rewrite appendAssociative (vl :: inorder rl) [v] (inorder r)
   in rewrite sym $ appendAssociative (inorder rl) [v] (inorder r)
   in rewrite appendAssociative (inorder ll) (vl :: inorder rl) (v :: inorder r)
   in Refl


instance Uninhabited (Here = There y) where
  uninhabited Refl impossible

instance Uninhabited (x `InTree` Tip) where
  uninhabited AtRoot impossible

elemAppend : {x : a} -> (ys,xs : List a) -> x `Elem` xs -> x `Elem` (ys ++ xs)
elemAppend [] xs xInxs = xInxs
elemAppend (y :: ys) xs xInxs = There (elemAppend ys xs xInxs)

appendElem : {x : a} -> (xs,ys : List a) -> x `Elem` xs -> x `Elem` (xs ++ ys)
appendElem (x :: zs) ys Here = Here
appendElem (y :: zs) ys (There pr) = There (appendElem zs ys pr)

tThenInorder : {x : a} -> (t : Tree a) -> x `InTree` t -> x `Elem` inorder t
tThenInorder (Node l x r) AtRoot = elemAppend _ _ Here
tThenInorder (Node l v r) (OnLeft pr) = appendElem _ _ (tThenInorder _ pr)
tThenInorder (Node l v r) (OnRight pr) = elemAppend _ _ (There (tThenInorder _ pr))

listSplit_lem : (x,z : a) -> (xs,ys:List a) -> Either (x `Elem` xs) (x `Elem` ys)
  -> Either (x `Elem` (z :: xs)) (x `Elem` ys)
listSplit_lem x z xs ys (Left prf) = Left (There prf)
listSplit_lem x z xs ys (Right prf) = Right prf


listSplit : {x : a} -> (xs,ys : List a) -> x `Elem` (xs ++ ys) -> Either (x `Elem` xs) (x `Elem` ys)
listSplit [] ys xelem = Right xelem
listSplit (z :: xs) ys Here = Left Here
listSplit {x} (z :: xs) ys (There pr) = listSplit_lem x z xs ys (listSplit xs ys pr)

mutual
  inorderThenT : {x : a} -> (t : Tree a) -> x `Elem` inorder t -> InTree x t
  inorderThenT Tip xInL = absurd xInL
  inorderThenT {x} (Node l v r) xInL = inorderThenT_lem x l v r xInL (listSplit (inorder l) (v :: inorder r) xInL)

  inorderThenT_lem : (x : a) ->
                     (l : Tree a) -> (v : a) -> (r : Tree a) ->
                     x `Elem` inorder (Node l v r) ->
                     Either (x `Elem` inorder l) (x `Elem` (v :: inorder r)) ->
                     InTree x (Node l v r)
  inorderThenT_lem x l v r xInL (Left locl) = OnLeft (inorderThenT l locl)
  inorderThenT_lem x l x r xInL (Right Here) = AtRoot
  inorderThenT_lem x l v r xInL (Right (There locr)) = OnRight (inorderThenT r locr)

unsplitRight : {x : a} -> (e : x `Elem` ys) -> listSplit xs ys (elemAppend xs ys e) = Right e
unsplitRight {xs = []} e = Refl
unsplitRight {xs = (x :: xs)} e = rewrite unsplitRight {xs} e in Refl

unsplitLeft : {x : a} -> (e : x `Elem` xs) -> listSplit xs ys (appendElem xs ys e) = Left e
unsplitLeft {xs = []} Here impossible
unsplitLeft {xs = (x :: xs)} Here = Refl
unsplitLeft {xs = (x :: xs)} {ys} (There pr) =
  rewrite unsplitLeft {xs} {ys} pr in Refl

splitLeft_lem1 : (Left (There w) = listSplit_lem x y xs ys (listSplit xs ys z)) ->
                 (Left w = listSplit xs ys z) 

splitLeft_lem1 {w} {xs} {ys} {z} prf with (listSplit xs ys z)
  splitLeft_lem1 {w}  Refl | (Left w) = Refl
  splitLeft_lem1 {w}  Refl | (Right s) impossible

splitLeft_lem2 : Left Here = listSplit_lem x x xs ys (listSplit xs ys z) -> Void
splitLeft_lem2 {x} {xs} {ys} {z} prf with (listSplit xs ys z)
  splitLeft_lem2 {x = x} {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {z = z} Refl | (Left y) impossible
  splitLeft_lem2 {x = x} {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {z = z} Refl | (Right y) impossible

splitLeft : {x : a} -> (xs,ys : List a) ->
            (loc : x `Elem` (xs ++ ys)) ->
            Left e = listSplit {x} xs ys loc ->
            appendElem {x} xs ys e = loc
splitLeft {e} [] ys loc prf = absurd e
splitLeft (x :: xs) ys Here prf = rewrite leftInjective prf in Refl
splitLeft {e = Here} (x :: xs) ys (There z) prf = absurd (splitLeft_lem2 prf)
splitLeft {e = (There w)} (y :: xs) ys (There z) prf =
  cong $ splitLeft xs ys z (splitLeft_lem1 prf)

splitMiddle_lem3 : Right Here = listSplit_lem y x xs (y :: ys) (listSplit xs (y :: ys) z) ->
                   Right Here = listSplit xs (y :: ys) z

splitMiddle_lem3 {y} {x} {xs} {ys} {z} prf with (listSplit xs (y :: ys) z)
  splitMiddle_lem3 {y = y} {x = x} {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {z = z} Refl | (Left w) impossible
  splitMiddle_lem3 {y = y} {x = x} {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {z = z} prf | (Right w) =
    cong $ rightInjective prf  -- This funny dance strips the Rights off and then puts them
                               -- back on so as to change type.


splitMiddle_lem2 : Right Here = listSplit xs (y :: ys) pl ->
                   elemAppend xs (y :: ys) Here = pl

splitMiddle_lem2 {xs} {y} {ys} {pl} prf with (listSplit xs (y :: ys) pl) proof prpr
  splitMiddle_lem2 {xs = xs} {y = y} {ys = ys} {pl = pl} Refl | (Left loc) impossible
  splitMiddle_lem2 {xs = []} {y = y} {ys = ys} {pl = pl} Refl | (Right Here) = rightInjective prpr
  splitMiddle_lem2 {xs = (x :: xs)} {y = x} {ys = ys} {pl = Here} prf | (Right Here) = (\Refl impossible) prpr
  splitMiddle_lem2 {xs = (x :: xs)} {y = y} {ys = ys} {pl = (There z)} prf | (Right Here) =
    cong $ splitMiddle_lem2 {xs} {y} {ys} {pl = z} (splitMiddle_lem3 prpr)

splitMiddle_lem1 : Right Here = listSplit_lem y x xs (y :: ys) (listSplit xs (y :: ys) pl) ->
                   elemAppend xs (y :: ys) Here = pl

splitMiddle_lem1 {y} {x} {xs} {ys} {pl} prf with (listSplit xs (y :: ys) pl) proof prpr
  splitMiddle_lem1 {y = y} {x = x} {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {pl = pl} Refl | (Left z) impossible
  splitMiddle_lem1 {y = y} {x = x} {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {pl = pl} Refl | (Right Here) = splitMiddle_lem2 prpr

splitMiddle : Right Here = listSplit xs (y::ys) loc ->
              elemAppend xs (y::ys) Here = loc

splitMiddle {xs = []} prf = rightInjective prf
splitMiddle {xs = (x :: xs)} {loc = Here} Refl impossible
splitMiddle {xs = (x :: xs)} {loc = (There y)} prf = cong $ splitMiddle_lem1 prf

splitRight_lem1 : Right (There pl) = listSplit (q :: xs) (y :: ys) (There z) ->
                  Right (There pl) = listSplit xs (y :: ys) z

splitRight_lem1 {xs} {ys} {y} {z} prf with (listSplit xs (y :: ys) z)
  splitRight_lem1 {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {y = y} {z = z} Refl | (Left x) impossible
  splitRight_lem1 {xs = xs} {ys = ys} {y = y} {z = z} prf | (Right x) =
    cong $ rightInjective prf  -- Type dance: take the Right off and put it back on.

splitRight : Right (There pl) = listSplit xs (y :: ys) loc ->
             elemAppend xs (y :: ys) (There pl) = loc
splitRight {pl = pl} {xs = []} {y = y} {ys = ys} {loc = loc} prf = rightInjective prf
splitRight {pl = pl} {xs = (x :: xs)} {y = y} {ys = ys} {loc = Here} Refl impossible
splitRight {pl = pl} {xs = (x :: xs)} {y = y} {ys = ys} {loc = (There z)} prf =
  let rec = splitRight {pl} {xs} {y} {ys} {loc = z} in cong $ rec (splitRight_lem1 prf)


---------------------------
-- tThenInorder is a bijection from ways to find a particular element in a tree
-- and ways to find that element in its inorder traversal. `inorderToFro`
-- and `inorderFroTo` together demonstrate this by showing that `inorderThenT` is
-- its inverse.

||| `tThenInorder t` is a retraction of `inorderThenT t`
inorderFroTo : {x : a} -> (t : Tree a) -> (loc : x `Elem` inorder t) -> tThenInorder t (inorderThenT t loc) = loc
inorderFroTo Tip loc = absurd loc
inorderFroTo (Node l v r) loc with (listSplit (inorder l) (v :: inorder r) loc) proof prf
  inorderFroTo (Node l v r) loc | (Left here) =
    rewrite inorderFroTo l here in splitLeft _ _ loc prf
  inorderFroTo (Node l v r) loc | (Right Here) = splitMiddle prf
  inorderFroTo (Node l v r) loc | (Right (There x)) =
    rewrite inorderFroTo r x in splitRight prf

||| `inorderThenT t` is a retraction of `tThenInorder t`
inorderToFro : {x : a} -> (t : Tree a) -> (loc : x `InTree` t) -> inorderThenT t (tThenInorder t loc) = loc
inorderToFro (Node l v r) (OnLeft xInL) =
  rewrite unsplitLeft {ys = v :: inorder r} (tThenInorder l xInL)
  in cong $ inorderToFro _ xInL
inorderToFro (Node l x r) AtRoot =
  rewrite unsplitRight {x} {xs = inorder l} {ys = x :: inorder r} (tThenInorder (Node Tip x r) AtRoot)
  in Refl
inorderToFro {x} (Node l v r) (OnRight xInR) =
  rewrite unsplitRight {x} {xs = inorder l} {ys = v :: inorder r} (tThenInorder (Node Tip v r) (OnRight xInR))
  in cong $ inorderToFro _ xInR
```